# Ruby - regex for formatting string representing time left

Tags: ruby, regex

I have various strings that represent time left coming in from a data feed.  The formats look like this:

- 13:35
- 01:36
- 00:34

I want to use regex to change the formats to:

- 13:35 --> 13:35 (ok as-is)
- 01:36 --> 1:36 (removing leading 0)
- 00:34 --> 0:34 (remove first leading 0)

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
time_left.gsub(/\A0+/, '')
```

Accomplishes first two target formats, but not the third, which results in:

:34 (should be 0:34)

Comment: Don't bother removing leading zeros. You'll want to convert the values to integers, or parse them, which will make the leading zeros a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `/\A0+/` removes *all* leading 0s, but it sounds like you just want to remove the first one. You just want `/\A0/`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex are not the best choice for this. I'd go after this like, ... uh, this:

```
puts %w[
  13:35
  01:36
  00:34
].map { |s|
  "%0d:%0d" % s.split(':').map(&:to_i)
}
```

Which outputs:

```
13:35
1:36
0:34
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the + that means 1 or more. So it will take two zeros if it has two zeros.

```
time_left.gsub(/\A0/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If each of the times are in a separate string and you are applying the regex individually to them, then, you should not use `gsub`:

```
time_left.sub(/\A0/, "")
```

If is rather the case that all the times are in a single string, then you cannot use `\A`.

```
time_left.gsub(/(?!<\d)0/, "")
```

The second one will also remove zeros after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a negative look-ahead:

```
/\A0+(?!:)/
```

( Tested in Perl )